# How to perform discrete root finding in R?

Tags: r

A typical statistics problem would be to find the minimal sample size for a known binomial process to guarantee that it would not fall below a certain threshold with a given probability. In R, `uniroot` would normally solve such problems, but because R uses gamma and digamma functions to evaluate the combinatorial probabilities, non-discrete sample size values render outrageous values that cause the root finding algorithm to fail.

For instance: suppose the vector X of Bernoulli has success probability 0.5. How many X must we sample to guarantee the sample average of X has a 20% chance of being lower than 0.3.

```
f <- function(n) pbinom(q = 0.3*n, size = n, prob = 0.5, lower.tail = F) - 0.8
```

[image]

```
> uniroot(f, interval=c(5, 20))
Error in uniroot(f, interval = c(10, 20)) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

Grid search becomes infeasible as we consider larger sample sizes and more precise intervals.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks, I was working on a solution that involves recursion, but it seemed like a cheap hack for dynamic programming - that was the line of thinking that led me to ask here.

Comment: By restricting to *integer* values of $n$ we get the same pattern,
which means that there are several integer solutions $n$ of $f(x)> 0$
with $5 \leq x \leq 20$, while no integer solution of $f(x) = 0$ seems
to exist. So the problem does not come from the non-integer
values. You can find all the integer solutions $f(x)> 0$ even on a
very wide interval because the evaluation of the function is very
fast.

Comment: A method that frequently works is to approximate the solution with a continuous model and then conduct a grid (or systematic) search originating at that solution.  Sometimes careful analysis is needed because in multiple dimensions the *Euclidean* distance between the optimum solution to the continuous version is far from the true optimal location.

Answer (score 4):

The discrete problem you are considering is not strictly a root-finding problem at all.  Instead, it is a matter of computing the smallest positive integer that meets a stipulated inequality condition.  Let me generalise the problem to suppose that we have $Y_n \sim \text{Bin}(n, \theta)$ and we are seeing the smallest value $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that:

$$\mathbb{P}(Y_n/n \leqslant \phi) \leqslant p.$$

In other words, we are seeking the smallest sample size such that the sample mean is no greater than $\phi$ with probability at most $p$.  (Your stipulated problem corresponds to the case where $\theta = 0.5$, $\phi = 0.3$ and $p = 0.2$.  Consequently, you are looking for the value:

$$\begin{align}
n_* \equiv n_*(\theta, \phi,p) 
&\equiv \min \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | \mathbb{P}(Y_n/n  \leqslant \phi) \leqslant p \} \\[6pt]
&= \min \{ n \in \mathbb{N} | \mathbb{P}(Y_n  \leqslant n \phi) \leqslant p \} \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

The simplest way to program an algorithm to find this value is to first recognise the monotonicity of the probability at issue, and then create an algorithm that runs through the integers $n=1,2,3,...$ and checks the inequality condition at issue.  Here is how you could program this in `R`.  In this case we see that $n_*=3$ is the smallest sample size meets your requirements.

```
#Set parameters
theta <- 0.5
phi   <- 0.3
p     <- 0.2

#Compute required sample size
n <- 0
PROB <- Inf
while (PROB > p) {
  n    <- n+1
  PROB <- pbinom(n*phi, size = n, prob = theta) }

#Show required sample size
n
[1] 3
```

More generally, if you want to find the minimum value that meets a condition, you can do this using a `while` loop in a similar manner as shown here.  You need to program an appropriate condition and expression to ensure that the loop will continue until the appropriate minimum is found.  You also need to check your input parameters to ensure that there will be at least one input value that meets the required condition, so that you don't get a loop that never terminates.

In some problems (much more complicated than the one given here) the number of integers to search prior to finding the minimum of interest may be so large that it is inefficient to run through the integers in this way.  In such cases we can often perform a preliminary step to "skip" a substantial number of preliminary values by first solving a continuous root-finding analogue to the problem to get an appropximation to the solution and then using this to create a smaller search area for the `while` loop.  For example, in a case like the present one ---involving binomial probabilities--- we could use the continuous approximation from the normal distribution (valid for large $n$) to find a continuous solution (which would involve root-finding for a continuous equation) and then we could create a search area that searches around this continuous solution point.

Comment: +1. But you can usually do much better than "running through the integers."  In this instance you could start at the optimum computed for the Normal approximation to the binomial and search in a neighborhood.  It takes a little analysis to determine how far you need to search.  (As a practical matter this is rarely an issue: when $n$ is big enough to be problematic, the continuous approximation will usually be excellent.)

Comment: @whuber: Good point.  I've expanded the answer to add this method.  In the present case the problem is so simple (and the solution only $n=3$) that a crude search is idea.